# Save Only File Name Using Spring MultipartFile (Annotation Based)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a domain class Organization which has a property called logo. The type of logo is MultipartFile. But the problem is I want to save file in a directory of WEB-INF/resource and save only the original file name into database. My domain class is as follows:

```
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private MultipartFile logo;
    @Column
    private String title;

    //getters & setters

}
```

And my JSP form is like bellow:

```
<f:form method="post" commandName="organization" action="${ requestScope.requestURI }" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <f:hidden path="id"/>

        <dt><f:label path="logo">Logo</f:label></dt>
        <dd><input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control input-sm"/></dd>

        <dt><f:label path="title">Title</f:label></dt>
        <dd><f:input path="title" class="form-control input-sm"/></dd>

        <dd>
            <f:button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</f:button>
            <f:button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Reset</f:button>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</f:form>
```

In my database I used VARCHAR as type of logo column. So now I want to upload file as MultipartFile and save file in a directory of WEB-INF. But remember I want to keep only originalFileName into my database logo field. Can you help me with showing controller implementation and other process. I m using spring annotation based configuration. So my configuration file as like:

```
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    /...
    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        cmr.setMaxUploadSize(1*1024*1024);
        return cmr;
    }
    //...
}
```

Can you help me in details? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the doc of Multipartfile??

Comment: @ShoaibChikate nope! Do you have doc link?